# FHIR - Patient (show) vs Multiple Patients (index/search)

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm new to FHIR and need to implement a simple interface. So far I'm trying to understand from the documentation the basics but there are lots of new terms so simple question...

**Patient/{ID}**

In this case I return a resource type of Patient with the details of a patient. So far so good!

**Patient?name.given=Joe&name.family=Blogs**

The above would be the index method. However, in this case I can return multiple patients.

What "type" or structure do I use to simply return an indexed list of responses?

I've seen possible candidates as List, Group, Composition and Bundle.

I need to know this generally so I can return the correct type for all "index" methods in RESTful Fhir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bundle.

```
{
 "resourceType:"Bundle",
 "type": "searchset",
 "entry":[...]
}
```

Check https://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html and see what you need to implement based on your requirments. As you can see almost everything in FHIR is optional.

Comment: Also look at http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html which describes searching in detail.

Comment: And look at the standard search parameters for your resource type, in this case Patient: http://hl7.org/fhir/patient.html#search. You would not search for name.given - the dot notation is used for chaining - and the search you want should look like: `GET [base]/Patient?given=Joe&family=Blogs`